# Local Bases for Discrete Topology

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

**Question:** Let $\mathbb{X}$ be any set and $\tau_{dis.}$ be the Discrete Topology. Consider the Topological Space $(\mathbb{X}, \tau_{dis.})$ and let $x \in \mathbb{X}$. Does $\mathscr{B}_x = \{\{x\}\}$ for a Local Bases at $x$?

Tried just looking this up, however, I do not see any results. Probably because it is a simple question.

**Proof:** Let $U_x \in \tau_{dis.}: x \in U_x$. It follows that $x \in \{x\} \subseteq U_x$. However, $\{x\}$ is open in the Discrete Topology and
$\{x\} \in \mathscr{B}_x$, hence, for every $U_x \in \tau_{dis.}: x \in U_x$, $\exists B \in \mathscr{B}_x$, namely $\{x\}$, such that $x \in B \subseteq U_x$. By definition this means $\mathscr{B}_x$ is a Local Bases at the point $x$.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question?

Comment: @questionasker yea let me edit it. Done.

Comment: Have you tried proving it? If so, where did you have a problem?

Comment: @RobArthan I will include my proof as well, and change the tone of the question to is my proof correct.

Comment: @RobArthan I included my proof. Is it correct?

Comment: Looks good. Well done.

Comment: @DuncanRamage Thank you.

Comment: I agree with Duncan.Well done.

Comment: @RobArthan Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that proof is correct. Note that $\{\{x\}\}$ is a local base for $x$ iff $x$ is an isolated point (i.e. $\{x\}$ is open) and in the discrete topology **all** sets are open so all points are isolated.